# Use a database value in a for loop within a foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a databound checkboxlist. I use the items in the checkboxlist in a nested loops. Within that foreach loop, I have a for loop that takes a number from user input and generates images from the desired amount. Each time a number is entered, that number is added to a database. Is it possible to have my for loop start wherever the value in my database is and then generate the number of images entered starting from the database value.

```sql
CREATE TABLE AccountTable
(
    RowID int IDENTITY(1, 1),
    AccountID varchar(2),
    AccountName varchar(50),
    SeqNum int,
    SeqDate datetime
)
```

```cs
public class dbvalue
{
    public int db_value { get;set; }
}

//OnClick Method
cmd.CommandText ="SELECT SeqNum FROM AccountTable;";
int i = Int32.Parse(amount.Text);
SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (sdr.Read())
{
    int k(int)sdr["SeqNum"];
    foreach(List item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {    
        for(int n = k; n <= i; n++) 
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                string barcode_label = item.Text + "QTY:___________";
                string barode_data = item.Value + datepicker.Text + n.ToSTring("D2");

                Bitmap dynImage = DrawBarcode(barcode_data, barcode_label)

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

                dynImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

                Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);

                img.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);

                panel1.Controls.Add(img);

                double spacing;

                double mg = 5;

                spacing = img.Width.Value + mg;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible to have the start value use a value from the database. It requires you to query the database and then set a variable.

Comment: forgot to add my command in my question, I am doing that, but it's acting strange where it starts at the user amount and generates ridiculous amounts, I'm assuming it has to do with the foreach loop and 1 value is selected it will generate the amount equal to all the numbers in the item list.

Comment: SeqQuant is not a column of the AccountTable described by your CREATE TABLE statement

Comment: also, you say "a number is added to a database" but none of your code contains an INSERT statement

Comment: sorry, I was mixing up code in my question. I'm not INSERTING anything to the database, the database already has rows and the user input is updating the rows. Those rows then reset after 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to query the database for the current value to start from, a query such as this would do it:

```
SELECT MAX(SeqNum) as MaxSeq FROM AccountTable
```

The easiest way to run such is by:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("that SQL here", new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
cmd.Connection.Open()
var maxseq = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

You now have maxSeq variable which is the max value of SeqNum in your table. Add 1 to it and make it your next insert

-

This will be fine if you only ever plan to use this app on one PC. If you're planning on having multiple computers insert into this table, you really should consider another form of counting the images - probably having the database do it with its identity column autoincrement, otherwise you'll run the risk that multiple records will have the same SeqNum value

Comment: So would I use it as `for(int n = maxseq; n <= i; n++)`?

Comment: well it works for a couple of tries but after I continue to generate to test, it stops generating images, unless the user enters in a number greater than the maxseq, but the counter in the database continues to update correctly.